# Write and retrieve JSON file to Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am writing a program that takes in the data from a large Google Sheet, treats and manipulates it and makes connection to other sheets in the same file. In order to improve my runtime and make a backup database.

I would like to store the data to a `JSON` file somewhere that I can easily use in Google Apps script again (I believe Google Drive is the best free option). How do I accomplish this?

I appreciate if you can show the exact codes that saves the following file to Google Drive and then reads it back into the script.

```
let listA = [{id: 34, performance: 200, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelwich'},
    {id: 35, performance: 300, supervisor: 'B', name: 'Aethelram'},
    {id: 36, performance: 400, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelham'},
    {id: 41, performance: 500, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelfred'}];

let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(listA);

// 1. code to save this jsonObject to Google Drive
// 2. code to retrieve the same saved JSON file back from google drive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
let listA = [{ id: 34, performance: 200, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelwich' },
{ id: 35, performance: 300, supervisor: 'B', name: 'Aethelram' },
{ id: 36, performance: 400, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelham' },
{ id: 41, performance: 500, supervisor: 'A', name: 'Aethelfred' }];

let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(listA);

// Save the data as a file.
const file = DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", jsonObject); // Or, if you want to put the file to the specific folder, please use DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID").createFile("sample.txt", jsonObject)
const fileId = file.getId();
console.log(fileId)

// Retrieve the data from the file.
const text = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // please set the file ID of the saved file.
const array = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(array)
```

#### References:

- [createFile(name, content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content)
- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getdataasstring)

Comment: thank you this is great! The Apps Script as well as the Spreadsheet is shared with other team-members. Do you know if they can also run this code? Should the folder where the file is being stored/retrieved be shared with them first?

Comment: @Ari Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `The Apps Script as well as the Spreadsheet is shared with other team-members. Do you know if they can also run this code? Should the folder where the file is being stored/retrieved be shared with them first?`, I think it's yes. If the user has permission, the user can run the script. But, I don't know about your detailed actual situation. So when this cannot be used, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.